# why div is not updated until the for loop is finished?

Tags: html, loops, display

In the following HTML page I expect the div being updated while the for loop is running. However, no div update occurs before the end of the loop?

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        
        <h1>why div is not updated until the for loop is finished?</h1>
        
        
          <div id="myBar"></div>
        
        
        <br>
        <button onclick="afficheHeure()">Click Me</button> 
        
        <script>
        var p1 =  document.getElementById("myBar");
        function afficheHeure(){
            for(i=0; i< 50000; i++){
                setInterval(function(){
                    let d = new Date();
                    let e = d.getTime();
                    p1.innerHTML = e;
                }, 100);
                console.log("i vaut = " + i);
            }
        }
        
        </script>
        
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript event loop clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658513/javascript-event-loop-clarification)

Comment: You are queueing all of the `setInterval` updates at the same time, meaning there won't be any time between them for the browser to update. In general, the browser only updates the screen at the monitor refresh rate (60x per second usually), so queueing all 50000 updates 100ms from now doesn't leave the browser time between them for redrawing, since about 16ms is needed between each update for it to get shown.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript Functions are "atomic" in the sense that they are not ever interrupted by "async" functions. `setInterval` registers a function to run asynchronously. It waits until no other functions are running before it runs.

Because you are registering functions with `setInterval`, those functions don't run until the interval has passed (and no other JS functions are currently running). However, `setInterval` itself is "non blocking": it just registers the function and then returns. Which means the function it registered has yet to run.

Let's a take a look at writing our own "setDelayed" function as an example (it won't actually wait for a specific interval, but it will let us register functions to run later):

```js
const queue = []
function setDelayed (delayedFunction) {
  queue.push(delayedFunction)
}

function runDelayed () {
  console.info('running delayed functions')
  while (queue.length) queue.pop().call()
  console.info('done with delayed functions')
}

// now we put or code with the loop


 for(let i=0; i< 5; i++){
   setDelayed(function(){
     let e = new Date().getTime()
     console.log({e,i})
   })
   console.log("registered i value", i)
 }

// and now we manually trigger our delayed functions, like JS would normally do automatically
 runDelayed()
```

Additionally, if you are making DOM updates (like your example), the browser actually waits for your script to finish before rendering any of those changes. So if you have a loop that takes long enough, the browser actually will "freeze" until your loop is finished. There are [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)s specifically to prevent this "freezing".

Comment: I used setInterval as an example which makes your answer correct. However, remove the setinterval and leave let d = new Date();
                    let e = d.getTime();
                    p1.innerHTML = e;

Comment: Sorry pressing enter just sent the comment. My point is that from inside the for loop updates on the div do not show up.

Comment: until the for loop is finished.

Comment: Added some more details. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var p1 =  document.getElementById("myBar");
var i = 0;
var bigArray = ['Hello','Hi','How Are You?','Welcome','Hello','Hi','How Are You?','Welcome','Hello','Hi','How Are You?','Welcome','Hello','Hi','How Are You?','Welcome'];
var itemsCount = bigArray.length;
function afficheHeure(){
  setInterval(function(){
    if(i < itemsCount){
      p1.innerHTML += bigArray[i]+'<br>';
      i++;
      console.log("i vaut = " + i);
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <h1>why div is not updated until the for loop is finished?</h1>
  <div id="myBar"></div>
  <br>
  <button onclick="afficheHeure()">Click Me</button> 
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want to speed it up, you can adjust the interval speed.

Comment: You are missing the FOR loop. This is where the problem stands: updating the DIV while running inside the FOR loop. Do something inside the FOR loop and at the same time update the DIV.

Comment: You can add the loop inside the array I named as bigArray.

Comment: Once again, the problem is when the for loop is outside like this: 
  function afficheHeure() {
   for (j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
    setInterval(function() {
     if (i < itemsCount) {
      p1.innerHTML += bigArray[i] + '<br>';
      i++;
      console.log("i vaut = " + i);

      console.log("count= " + j);
     }

    }, 100);
   }
  } you see that the for loop needs to end before the div is updated.

Comment: Check this:  var p1 = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var i = 0;
  var bigArray = [ 'Hello', 'Hi', 'How Are You?', 'Welcome', 'Hello',
    'Hi', 'How Are You?', 'Welcome', 'Hello', 'Hi', 'How Are You?',
    'Welcome', 'Hello', 'Hi', 'How Are You?', 'Welcome' ];
  var itemsCount = bigArray.length;
  function displayDiv() {
   for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
     console.log("i= " + i);
     console.log("j= " + j);
     p1.innerHTML += bigArray[j] + '<br>';

    }
   }
  } until the outside FOR loop is finished, no DIV display!